# upstream and downstream service

Tags: architecture, microservices, terminology

There are 2 services ServiceA and ServiceB. Purpose of ServiceA is to persist data and ServiceB is to process data.

API of ServiceA is triggered and it persists data in some database. Then it calls ServiceB to process the data. After processing ServiceB again calls ServiceA to persists the data. Here we are see calls go both ways in ServiceA and ServiceB.

As per my understanding,
Downstream service for ServiceA - Service it is making request to
Upstream service for ServiceA - Service it is receiving request from

By going through basic definition ServiceB acts as both upstream or downstream service which should not be the case. How we will mark the ServiceB here?

Answer (score 0):

You description is not very clear, but I understood the following call structure:

```
Client -> Service A -> DB

                    -> Service B -> Service A -> DB
```

If that is correct you are describing a circular dependency between sevice A and B and that seems to be a mistake in design and should be avoided by defining your service boundaries differently.

Without knowing more about the services and your decision to define the service boundaries this way we cannot really help with proposing alternatives.

Comment: Just provided a rough architecture. No issues with the design. But there is circular dependency between both of these services and was wondering which service would be treated as downstream service.